# Stop DatePicker from resetting the TimeOffDay when new date is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a DatePicker which displays the date only and a separate TextBox that displays the time. Both elements use TwoWay binding.

My issue is that when ever I adjust the date using the DatePicker, my time resets to 00:00. Is there a way to disable this behavior and leave the TimeOfDay alone? I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

I know I could grab the time with a GotFocus event and then manually restore, but it seems messy.

Comment: Which DatePicker?  There are lots out there.  Seems to me you could just unbind the textbox, though... is there any reason it has to stay bound to the date picker?

Answer (score 0):

The DatePicker and TextBox should be bound to two different source properties, a `DateTime?` and a `TimeSpan` respectively.

The built-in DatePicker control selects only a date without any specific time so it makes no sense to try to display the time of the selected date in a TextBox.